# woocommerce несколько страниц с каталогом

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

на woocommerce есть страница всех товаров по ссылке  домен/shop.
Мне нужна копия этой страницы, которою я хочу увидеть еще и по ссылке домен/shop-2

Comment: Точно копия? Или достаточно только товаров? Да отобранных по каким-то критериям (новые, рекомендуемые и тд)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в functions.php такой код:

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
    $shop_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^shop-2?', 'index.php?page_id=' . $shop_page_id, 'top' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'custom_rewrite_basic' );
```

И сохраните в админке структуру постоянных ссылок.

У вас будет выводиться точная копия страницы магазина. Но, поскольку многие стили завязаны именно на страницу магазина, выглядеть дубликат будет несколько иначе. Сравните http://test.kagg.eu/shop/ и http://test.kagg.eu/shop-2/ на моем тестовом сайте.

Comment: ооо. отлично. спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать страницу и использовать в ней шорткоды WC.
Напр

```
[recent_products per_page="12"]
```

Выведет последние добавленные товары (12 на страницу)

```
[featured_products per_page="12"]
```

Популярные товары.

И тд. 
Больше по шорткодам https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

Comment: на странице shop у меня есть фильтры по атрибутам, а как на новой странице их добавить?

Comment: Зависит от темы и плагинов